# Change page on TV browser with channel changer button on remote control?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, frontend, smart-tv-alliance

I'm trying to create a website and it's going to be used on Smart TV browsers...
I would like to facilitate user's navigation only using the channel changer button, so my question is:

Is it possible to make a function to detect <kbd>Channel Up</kbd> or <kbd>Channel Down</kbd> on my website and switch the page?

For example:
If I click on the <kbd>Channel Up</kbd> button on the remote control, it goes to page 2.
And if I click the <kbd>Channel Down</kbd> button on the remote control, it returns to page 1.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, [Samsung's documentation](https://www.samsungdforum.com/UxGuide/2014/03_input_method.html) suggests that Apps can intercept Channel Up. No word on how its Browser app handles that though. To be honest, this seems like kind of a strange UI you're making. Why not pick a button less surprising?

Comment: well, the browser doesn't send any keypress, only the "space" key when keyboard is detected, so it won't work, even if i choose other button... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to check: Is your TV sending the "key" press?
You can use simple JS+HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("x").innerHTML=event.which;
});
</script>
<p id="x">The keycode will appear here...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then write down the keycodes. If they aren't showing up, bad luck. Your TV isn't sending the keypress. If they are, using simple "if" you can navigate with Javascript.

Comment: thank you for the help... it didn't send the keypress

Comment: We are developing an HTML application which we want to run on smart TV/windows box. How do we handle actions on keypress of remote in html. Will the keycodes be different on different remotes ?